# Use of unassigned local variable. But always falls into assignment

Tags: c#, try-catch, unassigned-variable

having this code, I don't understand why if assigning a variable in a finally block doesn't understand it will ALWAYS be assigned. I think I missing a valid option where currency won't be assigned. If you know, will be great to understand why. much appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
CurrencyVO currency;

try
{
     if (idConnection.HasValue && idConnection != 0)
     {
         currencyConnection = client.GetConnection(idConnection.Value);
         model.Connection = currencyConnection;
     }
     else 
     {
         int providerUserKey = (int)Models.UserModel.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
         currencyConnection = client.GetConnection(providerUserKey);
     }                        
     currency = model.Currencies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.IdCountry == currencyConnection.idcountry) ?? new CurrencyVO();    
} 
catch
{
      currency = new CurrencyVO();                    
} 
finally
{
      model.PublishedContainer.Currency = currency;
}
```

the error happens on the finally block. If i take it out of the finally block like this :

```
                } catch {
                    currency = new CurrencyVO();
                }
                model.PublishedContainer.Currency = currency;
```

it works fine.

Comment: Yoy should state this post as a question

Comment: Replacing the last line of the Try block with "currency = new CurrencyVO();" causes it to not error, doesn't it?

Comment: @SpectralGhost: nothing inside the `try` block will change the error - `currency` needs to be assigned to before the `try` block (even if just assigning `null`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definite assignment tracking that the C# compiler performs doesn't necessarily perform a complete analysis (that wouldn't be possible in the general case) - there are rules that restrict how complex of an analysis the compiler will perform.  The rule covering the `finally` block here is documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691181.aspx:

> For a try statement *stmt* of the form:
>
> `try` *try-block* `finally` *finally-block*
>
> - The definite assignment state of `v` at the beginning of *try-block* is the same as the definite assignment state of `v` at the
>     beginning of *stmt*.
> - The definite assignment state of `v` at the beginning of *finally-block* is the same as the definite assignment state of `v` at
>     the beginning of *stmt*.
> - ...

So for your particular example, since `currency` is not definitely assigned at the beginning of the `try` block, it is considered to be not definitely assigned at the beginning of the `finally` block.

Comment: You beat me while I was testing the code :)  In the above example, if the constructor for CurrencyVO threw an exception, execution would hit the finally block with currency still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

What if `new CurrencyVO()` causes an exception in the `catch` block?  A-ha!

Comment: nice one. I leave the accepted to the more formal answer but this one was 'clever'. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can reason it out without hitting the language spec.  The failure mode here is that the statement in the catch block can throw an exception.  Quite possible, throwing an exception in a constructor is supported in C#.  But true in general, any statement can throw an exception.  Which will leave the variable uninitialized.  The assignment in the finally block will always execute.  And use an uninitialized variable in that case.

You'll need to think about what you to have happen in that case, if it is at all relevant.  But the obvious workaround is to simply initialize the variable to null explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `CurrencyVO` object inside the catch block: which will only execute if there is an error/exception. Therefore, if you encounter no exception: the `currency` variable will not get assigned. That's why you can't use it.

edit: make the following changes for your code to compile:

```
CurrencyVO currency = null;
```

and in finally:

```
if (currency != null)
   model.PublishedContainer.Currency = currency;
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a994a0ff-432b-4d23-b7d2-838b0b961de0

Comment: Currency is assigned in the last line of the try

Comment: @Joe: true, I noticed that later but I guess that compiler cannot guarantee that that assignment will be executed and that's why it doesn't allow use of the variable

Comment: Really? It seems like it will be assigned in the try or catch. One has to be caught, right?